# GWT Image Widget: Displaying only part of an image

Tags: html, image, gwt

I want to display only part of image using the GWT Image widget;

for e.g. for an image of 400X400, I want to use an image widget to display only the top left 100x100 px.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`setVisibleRect(0, 0, 100, 100)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#setVisibleRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)?